# How can I delete a Service Book in BlackBerry programmatically?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I am writing an application that will delete a certain Service Book at the phone's start up.
But I can't find the way to accomplish this.

How can I delete a Service Book programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

BlackBerry java SDK does not provide any API to delete a ServiceBook.

As an option, use EventInjector and inject a sequence of key events, to emulate user activity, to remove a service book. But it is not a trivial way neither an elegant one.